# Xcode doesn't see the. swift file in the obj-c project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, import

I want to use the swift class in my obj c code.
To do this, I

1. Created a .swift file and agreed to create a bridging-header
2. In the build setting set **Define Module** yes
3. Changed ProductName
4. in **SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME** wrote (ProductName) - Swift.h
5. In the .swift file itself, I added **@objc** to all keywords.

When adding to the .m file `#import "handtrackergpuapp-Swift.h"` returns an error that the file was not found.

Screenshot of project navigator:

[image]

Swift file and bridging-header located in SwiftFile folder. Trying to import from a file `HandTrackingViewController.mm`

[image]

Xcode 12.3, macOS 11.1

Comment: It's likely that you should import `(PRODUCT_NAME)-Swift.h` in your Objective-C code. `#import "Mediapipe-Swift.h"` if you did indeed use the product name from what I can see. Make sure you perform a clean build as well, after all, you're working with Xcode...

Comment: The fact is that when typing import xcode doesn't even tell me that I can import it

Comment: That's Xcode being Xcode. As my comment above suggests, perform a clean build and run your app. Xcode warnings are sometimes very misleading and not even true

Comment: I did a clean build, but in the process I get build failed

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried turning it off and on again? What exactly is the error in the issues navigator? Make sure you spelled the `SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME` variable correctly as well. In my project it is `$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Swift.h`

Comment: I did as you have, but the error is the same(I added a screenshot on top)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `HandTrackingGpuApp`, instead of `HandTrackerGpuApp`?

Comment: Yes, it must be handtrackinggpuapp, misspelled. But the error is still the same

Comment: That's wrong too, make sure to use the correct case.

Comment: I tried just importing .h file and xcode doesn't see it either

Comment: I'd like to see the error in the issues navigator, that is the fifth tab on the left pane. It will likely say something there. If you click the error, you might even be able to see somewhat of a trace causing your not found error